# How do I set all Strings variables to upperCase() in the whole spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot, uppercase

I'm in project of Spring Boot and I'm doing a task that I need to set Strings variables of all Classes in the code to upperCase.

I could use getter's to do that, but I wanna know if exists any configuration that I can use to make it more easier

My configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableScheduling
public class FooConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()   
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .build();
    }
}
```

What I don't want to do:

```java
public String getFoo() {
   return foo.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: Can you point out what exactly in the above code snippet needs to be uppercased?  Note that if you want to alter your class names, you would do best to use a refactor tool found in your IDE, rather than trying to do it by hand.

Comment: Also, if you want to change all variables ***names*** to uppercase I'd advise not to do so, as uppercase should only be used for `static final` properties, while all other properties should be kept camel case.

Comment: public String getFoo() {
        return foo.toUpperCase();
 } <<< I dont want to do that in the whole project

Comment: Might be a good usage for an apsect. It's been a while since I had a chance to play, but I believe you could define a pointcut for your getters (or setters) that would handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest other way I can think of is to use uppercase in the input.  I.E. the setters would do the editing:

```
public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = (foo != null) ? foo.toUpperCase() : null;
}
```

You would have to use this **religiously**, though.  Your constructors would have to use the setters instead of directly assigning the values.

It may be simpler to use your original solution.  With a null check.